# JS to PHP SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having some issues with Ajax POST and sending an array as a JSON.

I firstly get my data externally break it apart a little and then send it to my function.

```
const getPrices = async () => {
const now = Epoch(new Date());
    var company1 = $('#fcomp').val();
    var company2 = $('#lcomp2').val();
    console.log("Company1 =", company1);
    console.log("Company2 =", company2);
    
   const response = await fetch("https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol="+company1+"&outputsize=compact&datatype=json", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "f16d556786msh84b3a1e5cb78a33p172e62jsnb2827ccaab51",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
});

    await delay(5000);
    console.log("Waited 5s for API rules");
    
    const response2 = await fetch("https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol="+company2+"&outputsize=compact&datatype=json", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "f16d556786msh84b3a1e5cb78a33p172e62jsnb2827ccaab51",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
});

    const Prices = await response.json();
    const Prices2 = await response2.json();
    const just_prices = Prices["Time Series (Daily)"];
    const just_prices2 = Prices2["Time Series (Daily)"];
    
    sendToPHP(company1,just_prices);
    sendToPHP(company2,just_prices2);
```

this then sends (Or Should Send) the company code and the array

```
function sendToPHP (company,json){
    console.log("Attempting POST" );
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",  //type of method
        url  : "daily_push.php",  //your page
        dataType: 'json',
        data : { company : company, json : json },// passing the values
        success: function(res){  
                console.log("Successful POST Response:", res );
                },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error Occured in POST: ", errorThrown);
            console.log("Error Occured in POST: ", textStatus);
            console.log("Error Occured in POST: ", XMLHttpRequest);
            console.log("JSON: ", json);
        }
    });
    
}
```

im Debugging in Chrome Dev and am getting this responce:
*"SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0"*

I dump my Data Afterwards and it all Looks OK!?
[image: JSON Dump]

Im a little stumped now after searching around for an hour or so....

If I have missed something glaringly obvious I can only appologies for wasting your time!

EDIT 1:
More info (Prices Ouput)
here is the output from Prices:

[image: Explanded]

[[image: Minimised]]
Still not sure what is going on with it? hey all seem to be Objects. ONly thing I can think is that I need to maybe unpack each indevidual object thats held in tha dates then pass it back?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but it's very strange to see you using both `fetch` and jQuery `$.ajax` in the same code.

Comment: Have you logged `Prices` and `Prices2`, or inspected the response to those queries in the devtools? It appears that one of those is causing the problem - and it's not clear how your screenshot relates to them.

Comment: @RobinZigmond - the above Image is from console.log("JSON: ", json); This is whats actually being sent in the function so I thought it most relevant? I will output the Prices and see whats going on there as well. Thanks.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have updated the Origional post with the additional Prices data. Im still not sure whats going on with it though?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having is I was Sending `dataType: 'json',` whereas it should have been `dataType: 'html',` This then gets recieved by the PHP script and Successfully responds.
See image.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",  //type of method
    url  : "daily_push.php",  //your page
    dataType: 'html',
    data : { company : company, json : json },// passing the values
    success: function(res){  
            console.log("Successful POST Response:", res );
            },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error Occured in POST: ", errorThrown);
        console.log("Error Occured in POST: ", textStatus);
        console.log("Error Occured in POST: ", XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log("JSON: ", json);
    }
});
```

[image: Successful responce]

Comment: So is your PHP script just dumping an array? If you want it in json format, pass your array to `json_encode`

Comment: Yeah it just dumps the array (for testing purposes).